# Css настройка горизонтального меню

Tags: меню, framework, html, css

Использую замечательный css фреймворк [HTML KickStart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/). И мне нужно настроить выпадающий список так чтоб он был не ниже родительской ссылки а слева от всего меню и на всю ширину.

стандартно так:

[image]

нужно так:

[image]

Помогите, я не могу никак сделать

Comment: Мало инфы, 
.menu li { position:absolute; left:0; top:50px; width:100%}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.menu li` убираем `position:relative`

`.menu ul` заменяем `width` на `100%`

Пожалуй самый простой способ, не вдаваясь в тонкости фреймворка.

Comment: .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.menu ul {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

Дальше думаю разберешься.